# Is 'of' as in 'drink of' an old usage?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, archaicisms, contemporary-english

> I drank **of** the jar.

Is this '*of*' an old usage?
But I can't find the proof for that.

Comment: [Here's some dead obvious "proof"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+drank+of+the&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20drank%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0) Probably the only reason it hasn't actually "flatlined" by now is that old texts (especially bibles) get quoted in more recent publications.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Today's language borrows freely and liberally from "old texts (especially bibles)". Also, the expression is not that rare today. See 1988, 1993 in my answer.

Comment: Btw, never treat ngrams as "proof". :)

Comment: More commonly, the receptacle containing the beverage imbibed is indicated by the preposition _with_, or the compound preposition _out of_: “He always drinks milk out of/from a glass”.

Answer (score 1):

This tends to be an older usage.

It's not hard proof, but you will find a comparison of different versions of the same [bible verse here](http://biblehub.com/genesis/9-21.htm) of varying degrees of antiquity.

They compare a line in the book of Genesis

> And he drank of the wine, and was drunken; and he was uncovered within his tent."
>     -King James Bible published 1611

Many of the newer versions of the bible use the line:

> He drank some of the wine, became drunk, and uncovered himself inside his tent.
>    -New International Version published 1978 and revised since.

Comment: As OED says, *Const. **of** (rarely **upon**) the liquid or source of supply. lit. and fig.* to drink of the cup of sorrow , etc. So it could feasibly be used of a "jar". But you wouldn't see it often today except in outdated bibles.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would be careful calling _any_ bible _outdated_, unless you do mean it as Muslim rhetoric... ;)

Comment: @oerkelens Don't get us Jews started … we gave you a book and you *wrote all over it!*

Comment: You didn't give me no book!

Comment: @oerkelens You're right, I've made an assumption that you were a Christian. I apologize.  I shall atone for this error in the usual manner.

Comment: @oerkelens: From my point of view, the mere *existence* of bibles is "outdated", but that's not what I meant. I was simply agreeing with David that the *"drank **of**"* usage is generally recognised as outdated, and therefore "modern" contemporary bibles avoid it. If it's in any recently-printed bible, that will only be because the text of that particular version hasn't been revised in generations. Basically, it never occurs in *any* contemporary text except where deliberate archaism is intended.

Answer (score 0):

This usage of *of* relates to the stuff that is consumed, not the container -- the "jar" I suppose symbolically represents its contents here (the context should make it clear).

The closest dictionary definition of contemporary use is:

> **[of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of?q=of) 7** Indicating the relationship between a verb and an indirect object

You can find its use in literature.

*Sacred hot springs making a comeback in Europe*, NPR_Sunday, 2002:

> Mr-MOLDOVEANA: These waters were mysterious. If you **drank of** normal waters, which was transparent and fresh, and all of a sudden, you will find a water which is reddish or greenish, boiling, foul-smelling, you will be inclined to think that this is monstrous water, this is a force directed against you, against your well-being.

*The swamp of dreams*, Harper's Magazine, 1993:

> After eating these, he **drank of** the cool water of a shallow brook, then washed his face, further clearing his mind.

*Warriors of Christendom*, 1988:

> … he took of that balsam and of that myrrh as much as a little spoon-full, and mingled it in the cup with rose-water and **drank of** it; …

*War in high heels*, 1993:

> Later, Jacqui met her kiss for kiss in their lovemaking; even taking the initiative as they **drank of** each other 's bodies.

[COCA/ BNC]

Comment: You're not seriously going to advance that "Mr-MOLDOVEANA" citation as "literature", are you? It's complete drivel, with tenses bouncing around all over the place!

Comment: Uh, I agree with Kris that the verb phrase "drink of the" should be, or at least typically is, followed by a noun phrase meaning a **liquid** (or perhaps a body of liquid): drink of the wine (or perhaps drink of the stream). To me, it is not followed by a noun phrase meaning a *container*: drink of the wine bottle. (But I'm no expert on this stuff.  Just sounds wrong.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The tenses are firmly in place. Check again. :)

Comment: Switching from past to future for no apparent reason and using a singular verb with a plural noun counts as “firmly in place”?